# DBT2 password problems

Tags: mysql, benchmarking

So, I'm trying to run DBT2 benchmark on MySQL database.  (Which I downloaded from [MySQL site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/benchmarks.html).) After few days of fixing MySQL configuration, I was finally able to at least populate the test database.  However... the test doesn't run because it tries to log into a database w/o using a password, even though I supply it with one.  At least, this is my interpretation of what happens:

```
./run_mysql.sh --password mypassword \
               --lib-client-path $(which mysql) \
               --connections 20 \
               --time 300 \
               --warehouses 3
```

This results in:

```
cat /root/output/0/client/error.log
Wed Jan 16 15:48:40 2019
Microseconds : 473767
tid:980301568 mysql/dbc_common.c:50
Connection to database 'dbt2' failed.
Wed Jan 16 15:48:40 2019
Microseconds : 473845
tid:980301568 mysql/dbc_common.c:52
mysql reports: 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Wed Jan 16 15:48:40 2019
Microseconds : 473870
tid:980301568 db_threadpool.c:100
connect_to_db() error, terminating program
```

From the amount of struggle I had to put to run this test against vanilla MySQL, I believe that the test is no longer maintained / nobody ran it on recent versions of MySQL, but maybe someone of you know a way to configure it so that it does supply a password?  Short of editing the test source code (which I'd like to avoid in order to avoid any claims of tampering with the tests).

Comment: If `run_mysql.sh` is a shell script, is it executing the mysql client? If so, you can create a [config file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html) `~/.my.cnf` to define a default client password. But that's only used by MySQL clients like `mysql` or `mysqldump`. If their benchmarking tool does not use the mysql client, it won't have any effect.

Comment: Alternative: Remove the password from your MySQL root user. Should be okay if this is just a test instance of MySQL (it's not good to remove authentication for production MySQL of course).

Comment: @BillKarwin I didn't know this was possible, do you have a link to the manual which explains how to do this?

Comment: @BillKarwin reading through source of the test: no, they don't use `mysql`, they've written their own client.  And it doesn't even take a password as a parameter...

Comment: @BillKarwin nevermind, I figured out how to set password to empty string.  Which is what this test seems to be doing.  I also figured out that for some reason the `run_mysql.sh` won't work, but running `driver` and `client` on their own does seem to work.